# How do I send a image in this Tell a Friend script I'm using

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm trying to make a Tell-a-Friend type of script where a person fills out there name and a friends name and when they click send a E-Mail is sent to the friend showing a picture of a event that is being held.

**HTML:**

```
<form name=refer action="refer.php" method="POST">
<td align="center" valign="middle"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td height="30" colspan="2"><strong>Your Details</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">Name:
<input name="fromName" type="text" id="fromName"></td>
<td height="30">E-Mail:
<input name="fromEmail" type="text" id="fromEmail"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" colspan="2"><strong>Friends Details</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">Name:
<input name="toName" type="text" id="toName"></td>
<td height="30">E-Mail:
<input name="toEmail" type="text" id="toEmail"></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td height="30" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Refer"></td>
</tr>
</table></td></form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$fromName=$_REQUEST["fromName"];
$fromEmail=$_REQUEST["fromEmail"];
$toName=$_REQUEST["toName"];
$toEmail=$_REQUEST["toEmail"];
if ($fromEmail)
{
$ref=getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
if ($fromName=='')
$subject= "Your friend has referred you this link from www.sitename.com";
else
$subject= "$fromName has referred you this link from www.sitename.com";
$message = "
Dear $toName,
Your friend $fromName has referred this link to you.
Please visit this link by clicking $ref
";
$from = "From: $fromEmail\r\n";
mail($toEmail, $subject, $message, $from);
header ("location:".$ref);
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Email is not arriving or not even sending? Which webserver are you using? To your php: format it a bit, and use if { .. } else { .. } to make it a bit cleaner. After every header write exit();

Answer (score 0):

```
    $message = 'Dear '.$toName.',
    Your friend '.$fromName.' has referred this link to you.
    Please visit this link by clicking '.$ref.'. 
    Here is an image of the event: <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt="" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use free PHP libraries like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send emails with image attachments.

Or, if you wish to create your own image uploader, then I'd suggest reading about file uploads. You need to validate the authenticity of the image, check the extensions, and do all the other checks. Read more about file uploads in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/features.file-upload).

Hope this helps!